# Canvas context filter not applied on zoomed monitors

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, filter

I'm trying to apply a filter to the 2d context with `chart.ctx.filter = 'grayscale(100%)'` and the effect isn't created on scaled screens above or at 125%. The effect is applied when the screen zoom is at 100%.

How can I apply the effect to zoomed screens?

Comment: [Can't repro](https://jsfiddle.net/f2mzt0xh/), what browser? What OS? Is hardware-acceleration set? How big is the canvas?

Comment: This was on Chrome on Windows 10. Canvas is full screen. Harware acceleration is set.